# Mini DisplayPort to USB-C docking station - Surface Book

Tags: microsoft-surface, usb-c, mini-displayport

I have a first generation Surface Book. It does not have HDMI or USB-C. It does have a Mini DisplayPort. I also have a couple of monitors that are connected to a docking station that wants to connect to my laptop via USB-C. Evidently, it is not easy or possible to buy a USB-C to Mini DisplayPort converter that will actually allow the video output from my laptop to the dock and then on to the monitors. Am I wrong? Is there a solution to my problem? I am hoping someone can point me to a specific piece of hardware to buy. Thank you.

Comment: Hardware shopping requests are off topic on Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Am I wrong?": No. At the time of writing, there doesn't seem to be such a convertor available.
"Is there a solution to my problem?": Yes. Buy a mini DisplayPort hub (docking station).

Comment: Weird, cause I am not finding adapters that will allow the video to be transmitted from the laptop's Mini DisplayPort to the docking station's USB C. If you know of an adapter that will allow that then I would love to hear about it. Regarding the docking station, I sorta have to use it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's actually  USB c to mini DisplayPort that's easily available... Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using two adapters:
mini display port-->HDMI
https://www.walmart.com/ip/onn-Mini-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Female-Adapter-White/230508367

HDMI--> USBC
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08VDT3YGK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08VDT3YGK)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1204362)